# Additional sorting methods in right click menu in file manager

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, filemanager

Any way to get Group by and Sort by options in right click menu of file explorer? (like in windows).
**Ubuntu Studio 16.04.1**

Comment: You mean you dont want to use the `Alt+V` option (nor clicking on "View")? You want to use it through the Right_Click menu, right?

Comment: by going into view menu we can either  sort the files by name or group them by type....I want to sort files by name while the files are grouped by type (like windows we have 2 different options for grouping and sorting )...I want to achieve the same .....doesn't  matter how I do it...